# ASP.net MVC Partial view default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my create view in asp.net MVC, I have created more than 5 partial views and the views show and hiding according to the selected value from the combo box.
So as an example, If the user selects the **Request Type** as **Purchasing** then only the purchasing-related partial views will show and others will hide. This is currently working fine in my current coding. But when I load the page even the **Request Type** showed as **Purchasing** all the partial views will be shown to the user 1st time. Then again if I change the requesting type, partial views start to show and hide. So I tried using the default value assigning to the **Request Type** field but non of it worked. could you help me on this. Thanks.
Here is my code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Default box -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Request Header Details</h3>
                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove" title="Remove">
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReqType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReqType, ReqTypes, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReqType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                        <!-- /.card-footer-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Default box -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Request Main Details</h3>
                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove" title="Remove">
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--PurchaseSub-->
                            <fieldset id="pnlPurchaseEmp">
                                <legend><h5>If Purchasing Items for Employees</h5> </legend>
                                <ul id="RequEmp" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PurchasingEmpList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PurchasingEmpl Emp in Model.PurchasingEmpList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PurchaseEmployees", Emp);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="addAnotherEmp" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addAnotherEmp").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PurchaseEmpList', function (template) {
                                                $("#RequEmp").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="pnlPurchaseItem">
                                <legend><h5>Add Purchasing Item Details</h5></legend>
                                <ul id="ReqAttach" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PurchasingItemsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PurchasingItems Itms in Model.PurchasingItemsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PurchaseItems", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="addAnotherAttachment" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addAnotherAttachment").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PurchItemsList', function (template) {
                                                $("#ReqAttach").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>
                            <!--End of PurchaseSub-->
                            <!--GeneralSub-->
                            <fieldset id="pnlGeneralItms">
                                <legend><h5>General Request Attachments / Bills</h5> </legend>
                                <ul id="RequItms" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.GeneralItmsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.GeneralItms Itms in Model.GeneralItmsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_GeneralItms", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="addAnotherItm" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addAnotherItm").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/GeneralItmsPartialView', function (template) {
                                                $("#RequItms").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>
                            <!--End of GeneralSub-->
                            <!--SuspenseSub-->

                            <fieldset id="pnlSuspenseDetails">
                                <ul id="SusMain" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.SuspenseDetailsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.SuspenseDetails Itms in Model.SuspenseDetailsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_SuspenseDetails", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" id="addAnothersus" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addAnothersus").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/SusPartialView', function (template) {
                                                $("#SusMain").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <!--End of SuspenseSub-->
                            <!--Payment Voucher-->
                            <fieldset id="PaymentVoucher">
                                <legend><h5>Select the Payee for the Request</h5> </legend>
                                <br />
                                <ul id="PayVMain" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaymentVoucherList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaymentVoucher Itms in Model.PaymentVoucherList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentVoucher", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" id="addAnotherPayee" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addAnotherPayee").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentVouchPartialView', function (template) {
                                                $("#PayVMain").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset id="PaymentVoucherSettlements">
                                <legend><h5>Settlement Details</h5> </legend>
                                <br />
                                <ul id="ReqSettle" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaymentVoucherSettlementsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaymentVoucherSettlements Itms in Model.PaymentVoucherSettlementsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentVoucherSettlements", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" id="addSettlement" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addSettlement").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentVouchSettlements', function (template) {
                                                $("#ReqSettle").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset id="PaymentVoucherExpences">
                                <legend><h5>Details of Expenditure</h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="PayVExpen" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaymentVoucherExpenDetailsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaymentVoucherExpenDetails Itms in Model.PaymentVoucherExpenDetailsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentVoucherExpenDetails", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="addPayExpen" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#addPayExpen").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentVouchExpences', function (template) {
                                                $("#PayVExpen").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                             <!--End of Payment Voucher-->
                            <!--PayBill-->

                            <fieldset id="PaybillList">
                                <legend><h5>Invoice Related Supplier</h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="PayBill" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PayBillList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PayBill Itms in Model.PayBillList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PayBillList", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="AddSupplier" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#AddSupplier").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentBillPartial', function (template) {
                                                $("#PayBill").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="PaybillSettlement">
                                <legend><h5>Settling Previously Approved Request ?</h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="PayBillS" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaybillSettlementsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaybillSettlements Itms in Model.PaybillSettlementsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaybillSettlementsList", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="AddSettReq" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#AddSettReq").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentBillSettlements', function (template) {
                                                $("#PayBillS").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="PaybillRelatedAttachment">
                                <legend><h5>Upload the Relevant Documents </h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="ifsDoc" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaybillSettlingRelatedAttachmentsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaybillSettlingRelatedAttachments Itms in Model.PaybillSettlingRelatedAttachmentsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaybillSettlingRelatedAttachments", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="AddDoc" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#AddDoc").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentBillRelatedPartial', function (template) {
                                                $("#ifsDoc").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="PaybillInvoices">
                                <legend><h5>Invoice Details</h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="Invoices" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PaybillInvoiceDetails Itms in Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_PaybillInvoiceDetails", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="AddInvo" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#AddInvo").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/PaymentBillInvoPartial', function (template) {
                                                $("#Invoices").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>
                            <!--End of Paybill-->
                            <!--Vehicles Service-->
                            <fieldset id="VehicleService">
                                <legend><h5>Vehicle Details</h5> </legend>
                                <br />

                                <ul id="VDetails" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    @if (Model != null && Model.VehicleServiceDetailsList != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.VehicleServiceDetails Itms in Model.VehicleServiceDetailsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_VehicleService", Itms);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>

                                <button type="button" id="AddInfo" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                        $("#AddInfo").click(function () {
                                            $.get('/AppRequests/VehicleServicePartial', function (template) {
                                                $("#VDetails").append(template);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                            </fieldset>

                            <!--End of Vehicle Service-->
                            <!-- /.card-body -->
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                <fieldset id="pnlApproverList">
                                    <legend><h5>Add Approver to the Request</h5> </legend>

                                          <ul id="RequApprover" style="list-style-type: none">
                                        @if (Model != null && Model.ApprovalPartyList != null)
                                        {
                                            foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty Emp in Model.ApprovalPartyList)
                                            {
                                                Html.RenderPartial("_ApprovalView", Emp);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ul>

                                    <button type="button" id="addAnotherApprover" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function () {
                                            // $("#movieEditor").sortable();
                                            $("#addAnotherApprover").click(function () {
                                                $.get('/AppRequests/AddApproverToReq', function (template) {
                                                    $("#RequApprover").append(template);
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <br />
                                </fieldset>

                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-footer-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script>
    $('#ReqType').change(function () {
        // alert($(this).val());

        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            $('#pnlPurchaseEmp').show();
            $('#pnlPurchaseItem').show();
            $('#pnlGeneralItms').hide();
            $('#pnlSuspenseDetails').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucher').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherSettlements').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherExpences').hide();
            $('#PaybillList').hide();
            $('#PaybillSettlement').hide();
            $('#PaybillRelatedAttachment').hide();
            $('#PaybillInvoices').hide();
            $('#VehicleService').hide();

        }
        else if ($(this).val() == '2') {
            $('#pnlGeneralItms').show();
            $('#pnlPurchaseEmp').hide();
            $('#pnlPurchaseItem').hide();
            $('#pnlSuspenseDetails').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucher').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherSettlements').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherExpences').hide();
            $('#PaybillList').hide();
            $('#PaybillSettlement').hide();
            $('#PaybillRelatedAttachment').hide();
            $('#PaybillInvoices').hide();
            $('#VehicleService').hide();
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == '3') {
            $('#pnlSuspenseDetails').show();
            $('#pnlPurchaseEmp').hide();
            $('#pnlPurchaseItem').hide();
            $('#pnlGeneralItms').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucher').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherSettlements').hide();
            $('#PaymentVoucherExpences').hide();
            $('#PaybillList').hide();
            $('#PaybillSettlement').hide();
            $('#PaybillRelatedAttachment').hide();
            $('#PaybillInvoices').hide();
            $('#VehicleService').hide();

        }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Try creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all sections are visible and that's the problem.

options to solve:

1. call the function $ ('# ReqType') after document will be loaded, then the views will be set accordingly
2. Add a default empty ('0') value for the drop-down initial value and hide all parts of the view. the user will have to select the view type, which will make the changes